# llvm-rs-cc is missing Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've reinstalled Android Studio, but when I open up a new blank project, I get this error during the automatic first-time build:

> Cause: llvm-rs-cc is missing

The project has nothing in it. I recently uninstalled Android Studio, and I had deleted several of the projects in my documents folder. I have also just recently just restored from a System Image (where Android Studio had been installed... which I uninstalled when this error started popping up).

### Edit

I've been working on a large project for quite some time now and I have a lot of files and code. I finished the code some time ago, and I was just adding the content for already-made and implemented text files. The blank project I described above was me testing out to make sure the problem wasn't with my code.

I had finished up basically everything when this error popped up (right after the gradle upgrade to 4.6). As a final solution I'll completely reformat my computer, but I'm going to wait a few days to see if there are any solutions.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Alright, my bad.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to your **Android/SDK/build-tools** Folder

You will see folders named like :

21.1.2

23.0.3

25.0.1

Check whether **llvm-rs-cc** is Present in all the Folders, **Delete the folder(s)** where llvm-rs-cc is missing.

This will definitely Fix your Issue. Cheers...

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Saved my night :D Otherwise, my whole night was going to spoil.

Comment: @shivamsrivastava , I spoiled my entire day to find the cause of this issue LOL . I'm glad that I saved your time :D

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue using WSL, as I had installed the build-tools through windows the llvm-rs-cc file had the expected `.exe` extension.

To resolve all that was needed was a symbolic link allowing build tools that think they're running in linux to find the file:

```
//$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/x.y.z/

ln -s llvm-rs-cc.exe llvm-rs-cc
```

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me, too, on my Ubuntu build server but not on local build (MacOs). I just deleted the contents of my build-tools and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I have also met this problem after I updated Android Studio to Version 3.2.1 ,and then AS advise me to update my project to use build plugin **3.2.1** ,just show as below :

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`

this code snippet was the part of the root build gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}
```

then I sync the project ,and also met this problem:

> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':loopview:compileDebugRenderscript'.
>   llvm-rs-cc is missing

so I change the build **gradle plugin version back to 3.2.0** just as below show:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'`

and it build OK!
I also don't know the deal reason ,may somebody knew to share ~

**Attention**:
 my config version is :

- **buildToolVersion** is **28.0.2**
- **compileSdkVersion** is **28**

Comment: It's a temporary solution, but it works. Still trying to figure out a real solution to use 3.2.1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem & solved with following these steps:

1- in build.gradle (project ) change gradle version  to 3.2.1  :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

2- in build.gradle ( Module: app ) change config versions as:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
```

3- Sync Gradle & compile project :)))

- for BuildToolsVersion 28.0.3 you must update gradle version to 3.2.1

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted the folder `C:\Users\xxxxxx\.gradle` and restarted Android Studio, then it works good and fast..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure,

1. Your SDK path is set right (AndroidStudio -> Preference -> Android SDK Location -> Edit) to set it to proper location
2. If (1) didn't work for you try uninstalling all SDK versions and reinstall them fresh using SDK manager and resync your gradle and build your project once again.

Hop this helps !

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Right click on app on the left side

Then open : open module settings

set - Compile SDK version into maximum

set - Build Tool version into maximum

Then press OK 
wait for the tasks to run. i hope it will work for you also.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the SDK version you installed does not provide `llvm-rs-cc`. Go to your AppData folder (if it is hidden then set the settings to `show hidden files` and go to your SDK folder - build tools, to check if `llvm-rs-cc` is available. if no, proceed to Android Studio and go to Configure - SDK manager - SDK tools - show package details - install latest version 27. then, check under the same SDK folder to see if `llvm-rs-cc` is available. Run cordova run android on cmd again. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Chang classpath to latest verison then click on `sync now` after this clean project and run it. Your problem will gone. **HAPPY CODING**

```
open Build.gralde change classpath to latest with alt+enter.
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
open gradle-wrapper.properties change gradle version to latest with alt+enter


distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

And also change **compileSdkverison** and **buildToolsVerion** to latest verison.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.answer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please explain the changes you proposed in your answer?

Comment: change your classpath to latest version and also change compile and build version to latest verison. click on **sync now** and then clean your project. Cause: llvm-rs-cc is missing will gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was reinstall latest `Android SDK Build-Tools`.

- In Android Studio go to `File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior > System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools`
- Check `Show Package Details`
- Uncheck latest version (mine was `30.0.2`)
- Click `Apply` and confirm delete
- Then check again latest version, and click `Apply`

[settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjuAo.png)